# How to simulate timeouts with Fiddler

Tags: http, post, httpwebrequest, timeout, fiddler

I have a C# script that HTTP POSTs to another server with `WebRequest`. I'd like to test how my web application would respond if the other server became unresponsive. What is the best way to do this without having to change any of my application code or configuration? Will Fiddler be able to cause timeouts for requests coming from my local IIS?

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate at Server Fault?

Comment: If that helps, I found MUCH more helpful testing my web page from a Virtual Machine. Just download VMWare Player, download a free VM from here: http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/ and do your job. You must configure your network either with NAT or BRIDGED. Whatever works with you. Then reference your site with an IP. To cause a connectivity problem, disable your network connection from the top-right icons of the VMWarePlayer (right click on the network icon).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve it using the "Simulate Modem Speeds" rule.

1. Rules -> Customize Rules
2. Find the line that says "oSession["response-trickle-delay"]" and change it. Set it to 10000. It should be enough to cause time out. Save the file.
3. Rules -> Performance -> Simulate Modem Speeds (should be checked).

[Note: Use ipv4.fiddler instead of localhost.](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic)

Comment: (a) Note that 10000 = 10 seconds (b) You can of course make a particular route timeout using code like this: if (oSession.PathAndQuery=="/slowroute") { oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "1000000"; }

Answer (score 6):

Can be achieved on specific responses where you want to intercept the response as well as simulating latency by using "AutoResponder".
"Enable Latency" checkbox and right-clicking any rule to pick "Set Latency" you can then adjust latency in millisecond values.

Answer (score 0):

The other part of your question is "How do I get my service to use Fiddler", which has an answer here: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-IIS